# Error handling when opening a PDF in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf-reader

I am attempting to open a 3rd party generated PDF that I know will fail occasionally. I am trying both `pdf2json` and `pdfreader`, and am encountering the same issue, which I'm not sure if it how I am attempting to handle the libraries in a promise.

When I receive an PDF, I would like to open it, to ensure that it is a valid PDF before passing it on for processing.

I am doing it like so:

```
function printRawItems(filename, callback){
new pdfReader.PdfReader().parseBuffer(filename, function(err, item) {
    if (err) {
        callback(err);
    } else if (!item) {
        callback();
    } else if (item.text) {
        callback(null, item)
    } else if (item.page){
        console.log("page =", item.page);
        callback(null, item);
    } else if (item.x){
        console.log([item.x, item.y, item.oc, item.A, Math.floor(item.w), item.text].join("\t"));
        callback(null, item);
    } else {
        console.warn(item);
    }
});
}

function isValidPdf(buffer) {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    printRawItems(buffer, function(err, item){
        if (err) {
            return reject(err);
        } else if (item) {
            return resolve(item);
        }
        return reject();
    })
}).catch(err => {throw err})
}
```

The buffer being passed in to the "isValidPdf" is from an http request.

Now from what I can tell the callback I'm passing into the parseBuffer appears to get run twice. Once when the file is opened (and so item is "file"), and a second when it is parsed. After the first pass the promise in "isValidPdf" is resolved and the callback being passed in is never called, so it isn't rejected. The second run of the `parseBuffer` callback displays errors, which throws the exception, but by that time the promise is resolved and bad things happen.

Am I misunderstanding how the callbacks work, or are these libraries doing something wrong, and I should open a support ticket?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not misunderstanding how callbacks work. Just using them in the wrong way. I had a quick look at `pdf2json` and it seems you first create the parser, then do `.parseBuffer()` and wait for events to fire, e.g.:

```
function printRawItems (buffer, cb) {                                                                                                                                                                                
  const parser = new PDFParser()                                                                                                                                                                                     
  parser.on('pdfParser_dataError', errData => {                                                                                                                                                                      
    cb(errData.parserError)                                                                                                                                                                                          
  })                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
  parser.on('pdfParser_dataReady', pdfData => {                                                                                                                                                                      
    cb(null, pdfData)                                                                                                                                                                                                
  })                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
  parser.parseBuffer(buffer)                                                                                                                                                                                         
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. Going back to pdf2json from pdfreader, and using your example makes it exit immediately.

Comment: Exit immediately in what way?

Comment: I get no call back. I can only assume that the error handling in the application isn't using the data error output. At least in this scenario.

**Edit** I mean error handling in the library

Comment: Thanks, I've accepted this as it has help confirm my fear that the lib isn't working as expected. I can run through 0 byte pdfs and they return the error, and I can run through correct pdf's and they parse correctly. Corrupted pdf's appear to exit immediately, and don't throw an exception that I can handle.